# Count different values in a grouped by subset

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
data.frame(company=c("c1","c2","c3","c2","c1","c2"),field=c("A","B","C","A","D","C"))
```

I am interested to know

**How many different field each company have?**

So, i need to have a dataframe like below

```
company   filds

c1          2

c2          3

c3          1
```

Comment: Number (`length`) of fields or number of distinct (`length(unique(...))`) fields? The example is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` the 'field' by 'company' to find the `length` of 'unique' elements in each 'company'

```
aggregate(field~company, df1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
#   company field
#1      c1     2
#2      c2     3
#3      c3     1
```

---

Or using `data.table`, convert to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'company', use the convenient wrapper (`uniqueN` i.e. `length` of `unique`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(fields = uniqueN(field)), company]
#   company fields
#1:      c1      2
#2:      c2      3
#3:      c3      1
```

---

Or with `dplyr` with `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(company) %>%
    summarise(fields = n_distinct(field))
```

NOTE: In the example, the number of `unique` 'field' per 'company' and the total elements in 'company' are the same.  If it is the latter, then use `.N` from `data.table` or `n()` from `dplyr` i.e.

```
setDT(df1)[, .(fields = .N), company]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(company=c("c1","c2","c3","c2","c1","c2"),
                       field=c("A","B","C","A","D","C"))
```